# Linq to SQL rounding of decimal after division

Tags: sql-server, linq, decimal, rounding

I've come across a precision issue when calculating the ration between two units of measures.

The Ratio is stored in a SQL Server database in a UnitOfMeasureTable as: NumberOfDefaultUnits decimal(28,18)

In my linqPad example I have a class to demonstate what is going wrong.

```
 private class Test
 {
   public decimal saleUom { get; set; }
   public decimal piUom { get; set; }

   public decimal RatioRight { get; set; }
   public decimal RatioWrong { get; set; }
   public decimal CalcledAlsoRight { get { return saleUom / piUom; } }
}
```

void Main()
{

```
var xx = from uom in UnitsOfMeasures.Where(d=> d.Id == 9)
        let buyUom =  uom.NumberOfDefaultUnits
        let sellUom = UnitsOfMeasures.First(d=> d.Id == 13).NumberOfDefaultUnits
        select new Test

{
    saleUom = sellUom,
    piUom = buyUom,
    RatioRight = sellUom / (buyUom * 1m),
    RatioWrong = sellUom / buyUom,
};

xx.First().Dump();
```

}

The results are:

```
saleUom 453.592370000000000000 
piUom 1000000.000000000000000000 
RatioRight 0.000453592370000000000 
RatioWrong 0.0004535923 
CalcledAlsoRight 0.00045359237
```

It took a while to figure out you have to multiply the divisor by 1m to get the correct result. It gets even weirder if you multiply the sellUom by 1m. 
Then the result is:

```
RatioRight = (sellUom * 1m) / (buyUom)
RatioRight 0.000453
```

I'm guessing this is something to do with how SQL Server stores the Decimal(28,18) and how Linq converts the divide command.

Update: All values are Decimals
[image]

Update 2:
Looks like this is entirely a SQL rounding thing. Removing the .Net from the equation

```
 select top 1 uom.NumberOfDefaultUnits
      from UnitOfMeasures uom
      where uom.Id = 13

 select (select top 1 uom.NumberOfDefaultUnits
      from UnitOfMeasures uom
      where uom.Id = 13 ) 
    / 
      (select top 1 uom.NumberOfDefaultUnits
      from UnitOfMeasures uom
      where uom.Id = 9)
```

The first query returns: 453.592370000000000000

The second: 0.0004535923

Comment: Looks like `buyUom` is an `integer`. I'll bet it has something to do with that. If you multiply it with `1m` it gets converted to a `decimal`. I'm not sure in this case what the effect of a division of a decimal with an integer is.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Nope, buyUom is defo a decimal. it comes straight from the Decimal(28,18) column in the UnitOfMeasure Table. Will add a screenshot

Comment: Can you look what the value of `buyUom` is? It might be different from the value when assigned to `piUom` (with respect to significant figures).

Comment: @HoneyBadger The value of piUom? In the database it shows as "1000000.000000000000000000". I don't think this is a values problem. Look at the CalcledAlsoRight property. It runs 100% the same thing "saleUom / piUom" it gets the right answer but the version that is sent to SQL gets it wrong.

Comment: I think it has to do with significant figures. A decimal in .NET has 28-29 significant figures, in sql however many you define them as, so in your case it would be 18. That's why I expect `buyUom` to have a different number of significant figures then `piUom`. When decimals are divided the resulting precision and scale is calculated. I don't know how .NET does this, but I'm fairly confident your issues is caused by this. When you multiply by `1m` the significant figures is set to .NET default (28-29) again, which would change the resulting precision and scale.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Thanks I'll accept that as an answer. I'm still not understanding how multiplying sellUom by 1m reduces precision to 6 places. It's definitly something with how SQL decides precision vs the .Net

Comment: The 6 places got me stumped a bit too, especially because it is 6. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132900/discussion-between-mikey-mouse-and-honeybadger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely due to how SQL Server handles precision & scale in calculations.

If you change @mikeymouses example to use a scale of 6 for @p1 you get consistent results:

```
DECLARE @p2 Decimal(28,6) = 1000000
DECLARE @p3 Decimal(28,18) = 453.59237

 select @p3 / @p2

 DECLARE @p1 Decimal(19,18) = 1  -- This is how Linq sends the * 1m

 select @p3 / (@p2 *@p1)
 select (@p3 *@p1) / @p2
```

Results:

0.0004535923700000000000

0.00045359237000

0.00045359237000000000

The precision and scale outcomes are documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx), but the key points are:
For Multiplication:

- precision of result = p1 + p2 + 1
- Scale of result = s1 + s2

For Division:

- Precision of result = p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
- Scale of result = max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)

Where p1 and p2 are the precision of the operands and s1, s2 are the scale of the operands.

It should be remembered that the result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.
I think this is what is happening here.

Comment: Thanks for that. After a bit more playing around, that looks to be exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is just how SQL deals with these declared decimal sizes being divided by eachother

```
 DECLARE @p2 Decimal(28,18) = 1000000
 DECLARE @p3 Decimal(28,18) = 453.59237

 select @p3 / @p2

 DECLARE @p1 Decimal(19,18) = 1  -- This is how Linq sends the * 1m

 select @p3 / (@p2 *@p1)
 select (@p3 *@p1) / @p2
```

Results:

0.0004535923

0.000453

0.00045359